# Burning a 1080p slideshow onto Blu-Ray using Mac OS X

Tags: macos, software-rec, burning, blu-ray, 1080p

I'm trying to burn a 1080p slideshow onto a Blu-ray disc with my Mac. I've been able to make the slideshow in both iDVD and DVD Studio Pro, but neither support Blu-ray burning.

With what combination of software can I create, export, and burn such a slideshow? I'd prefer it if I can make the slideshow autoplay on disc load, as I can in the two programs I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toast 10's Blu-ray plugin is likely to be your only option on the Mac until Apple embrace Blu-ray authoring in iDVD or Final Cut:

http://www.roxio.com/enu/products/toast/plugin/overview.html

You should be able to export your iDVD/Final Cut project to Toast (or import from Toast directly) ready for a burn.